# How to add custom buttons to Summernote toolbar

Tags: javascript, summernote

Anyone else having problems with this? I followed the docs but the button is not showing up. It just creates an empty div. No errors in console.

Docs: https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#custom-button

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        toolbar: [
            ['mybutton', ['hello']]
        ],
        buttons: {
            hello: HelloButton
        }
    });

    var HelloButton = function (context) {
    var ui = $.summernote.ui;

    // create button
    var button = ui.button({
        contents: '<i class="fa fa-child"/> Hello',
        tooltip: 'hello',
        click: function () {
        // invoke insertText method with 'hello' on editor module.
        context.invoke('editor.insertText', 'hello');
        }
    });

        return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
    }   
});
```

Rendered HTML

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you,  Actually  i was missing  ` toolbar: [
            ['mybutton', ['hello']]
        ],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. So I had to put the HelloButton function outside of $(document).ready()

Comment: You're half right. The problem isn't that you defined your function inside `ready()` but that you referenced it before it was defined. If you defined HelloButton at the top of `ready()` but before `summernote()`, that works. Or better yet, don't even use a named function and simply define the function inline in the `buttons` map. By moving your function outside of `ready()` you accidentally fixed it, defining it before the reference.